# SQL query groupBy and filter

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pgadmin

I have two tables in my database which I need to join to obtain a list of User IDs. The first table stores the `user_id` and `email`:

```
user_id | email
-------------------------
1       | test@test.com
2       | test2@test.com
```

Table 2 contains searches of the user and the browser which they used:

```
id | user_id | browser
--------------------------------
1  | 1       | Internet Explorer
2  | 1       | Internet Explorer
3  | 1       | Firefox
4  | 2       | Chrome
```

I want to join the two tables together based on the `user_id` and filter out users who only ever used Internet Explorer.

My current query looks like:

```
select distinct (u.id,u.email) 
from users u join searches k on u.id = k.user_id 
where k.browser = 'Internet Explorer'
```

which is wrong as this will retrieve users who have used Internet Explorer before - but not exclusively only Internet Explorer.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list all users that have at least one search from a browser that is not Internet Explorer:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM searches s
  WHERE s.user_id = u.id
    AND s.browser <> 'Internet Explorer'
)
```

Comment: Nice, this is better and probably much faster than picking individual users and see if all their searches are on IE.

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that every user used at least one browser sometime, this can be done more easily by filtering the users where another browser exists:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.userid, u.email
FROM   users u
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   searches k
               WHERE  u.userid = k.userid AND k.browser != 'Internet Explorer')
```

If this assumption is incorrect, and you want to also allow users that have never used any browser, you'd need another condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.userid, u.email
FROM   users u
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   searches k
               WHERE  u.userid = k.userid AND k.browser != 'Internet Explorer')
       OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM   searches k
                      WHERE  u.userid = k.userid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following .

```
SELECT  u.id , u.email 
FROM    users u
    JOIN searches k ON u.id = k.user_i
GROUP BY u.Id , u.email
HAVING  MIN(k.browser) = MAX(k.browser)
    AND MAX(k.browser) = 'Internet Explorer'
```